# C++ How to make long computations work

Tags: c++, optimization

I am prototyping a voxel engine and there is no optimization like octree yet, so I am computing each voxel for culling which tooks very long time.
When I have a 16*16*16 voxel map to compute it takes like less than 0.1 secs to compute and render.

But when I have bigger maps like 100*32*100 it NEVER ends to compute ( waited 10 minutes still not rendering ), I have a white screen and the program is like stuck in an infinite loop but it shouldn't be infinite.

Is there a time limit for computation ?

EDIT:
Here is the loop for culling:

```
for (auto it = Chunk.begin(); it != Chunk.end(); ++it)
{
    if ((*it).w != 0)
    {
        Vector3f position = Vector3f((*it).x, (*it).y, (*it).z);
        Vector3f top(position.x, position.y + 1, position.z);
        Vector3f down(position.x, position.y - 1, position.z);
        Vector3f front(position.x, position.y, position.z - 1);
        Vector3f back(position.x, position.y, position.z + 1);
        Vector3f left(position.x + 1, position.y, position.z);
        Vector3f right(position.x - 1, position.y, position.z);

        auto findTop = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (top == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });
        auto findDown = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (down == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });
        auto findFront = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (front == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });
        auto findBack = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (back == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });
        auto findLeft = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (left == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });
        auto findRight = std::find_if(Chunk.begin(), Chunk.end(), [=](Vector4f vec) { if (right == Vector3f(vec.x, vec.y, vec.z)) { return true; } else { return false; } });

        bool isTopOpaque, isDownOpaque, isFrontOpaque, isBackOpaque, isLeftOpaque, isRightOpaque;

        if (findTop == Chunk.end())
            isTopOpaque = false;
        else
            isTopOpaque = findTop->w;

        if (findDown == Chunk.end())
            isDownOpaque = false;
        else
            isDownOpaque = findDown->w;

        if (findFront == Chunk.end())
            isFrontOpaque = false;
        else
            isFrontOpaque = findFront->w;

        if (findBack == Chunk.end())
            isBackOpaque = false;
        else
            isBackOpaque = findBack->w;

        if (findLeft == Chunk.end())
            isLeftOpaque = false;
        else
            isLeftOpaque = findLeft->w;

        if (findRight == Chunk.end())
            isRightOpaque = false;
        else
            isRightOpaque = findRight->w;

        if (!(isTopOpaque && isDownOpaque && isFrontOpaque && isBackOpaque && isLeftOpaque && isRightOpaque))
        {
            glm::mat4 modelM = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.0 * position.x, position.y * 2.0, 2.0 * position.z));
            size++;
            modelMatrices.push_back(modelM);
        }
    }   
}
```

"Chunk" is a std::vector of 4d vector, (x,y,z) are the position and (w) indicates if it's opaque (1) or not (0). I am using VS2013 IDE.

Comment: Just calculate big oh for your algorithm. Plug in the numbers and see how bad it is :)

Comment: With no code, and not even a mention of your target environment, it's impossible to say much that would be useful.

Comment: Your algorithm is perhaps inefficient. You might read math books to improve it. You might parallelize it. And you should ask the compiler to optimize it. Show more source code, show your compilation command and your environment (compiler, operating system)! Edit your question to improve it!

Comment: It sounds like you're storing your voxel as a (unordered?) list of coordinates, which means any spatial referencing requires a search through the list.  That's an inefficient way to store spatial data.  You also refer to your voxel as 16x16x16.  Does that mean that the locations are, in fact, rectangular and evenly spaced?  Then just store a 16*16*16 vector of bool to represent your voxel, along with the dimensions.  Looking up `w` is now just an indexing operation, preceded by a 3D limit check.

Comment: "it NEVER ends": did you wait until the end of time ?

Answer (score 2):

Those 6 find_if calls are doing linear searches for each iteration of the loop and comparing the vectors. The algoritm is order of N^2 which will be slow for larger cases.

If your vector contains 1000 elements, the find_if calls could potentially compare 6,000,000 elements in the worst case. At 2000 elements, it jumps to 24,000,000 comparisons.

If you are running VS 2013 Professional or above, just profile the code for a smaller case and see where the algorithm is spending it's time. Step 1 of fixing a performance problem is collecting real measurements to see what needs to be improved.

Comment: Large case doesn't even be that large. If `16*16*16` took 0.1 s, then `100*32*100` will take about an hour and half.

Comment: I agree. I edited my answer to give an example, N^2 * 6 goes up really fast as N increases.